# Get SQL query result in Datatable using Servicestack ormlite

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to Servicestack Ormlite.

I want to execute the SQL query on database using Servicestack Ormlite and get the results in datatable.

SQL query will be generated randomly, containing different tables, columns each time. So I can't use poco class for the same.

We are using SQL Server as the database.

Answer (score 2):

OrmLite doesn't support or have any dependencies on DataTables or DataSets which as a code-first POCO ORM is strictly opposed against the use of.

See the [Dynamic Result Set docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets) for examples of querying untyped structures, either in a object List:

```
db.Select<List<object>>(db.From<Poco>()
  .Select("COUNT(*), MIN(Id), MAX(Id)"));
```

Or Dictionary:

```
db.Select<Dictionary<string,object>>(db.From<Poco>()
  .Select("COUNT(*) Total, MIN(Id) MinId, MAX(Id) MaxId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***CreateCommand*** method to get a datareader, like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();  
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
using (var cmd = db.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from [table]";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns == null || dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(reader.GetName(j), reader.GetFieldType(j));
                    }
                }
                var cell = reader.GetValue(i);
                row[i] = cell;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```